# Loading dll that contains Newtonsoft assembly with reflection error

Tags: c#, reflection, json.net

I'm trying to load an assembly using reflection that uses the `ISerializationBinder` binder from Newtonsoft, but when the assembly is loaded it throws the following exception:

> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: 'Unable to load one or
>   more of the requested types. Could not load type
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.SerializationBinder' from assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json,
>   Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'.'

I don't really have a clue of why it could be

Comment: If you are using VisualStudio, use NuGet to make sure that the Json.Net package is loaded in your project and that all the versions are the same.
If not using VS or NuGet, check that the Json.Net assembly is referenced by the running assembly.
If you have any warnings during build, please add that information to your question.

Comment: @Derrick Hey, so I have no warnings and all projects that use this assembly have newtonsoft installed with the same version

Comment: FYI, [`Newtonsoft.Json.SerializationBinder`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/11.0.2/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/SerializationBinder.cs) is obsolete in 11.0 (actually as of [10.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/10.0.1) I believe).  Instead when creating a custom serialization binder they recommend implementing their own interface [`ISerializationBinder`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeSerializationBinder.htm).

Comment: @dbc Well, the funny thing about it is that I recently made that change. I used to use the serializationBinder class and extend from it but now I'm using the interface

Answer (score 1):

Well, honestly I'm still confused but I did a clean and then build of the assembly I was trying to load and that seemed to get rid of the old SerializationBinder class.

Comment: I've seen this. Sometimes build-clean can fix stuff like this.