# C# The type initializer for 'Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultSerializationBinder'

Tags: c#, json, json.net

What I'm trying to do is convert a JSON file into arrays that I can utilize later on in the C# script but for some reason, I can't get it to work. Either the JSON lib doesn't want to load or when I do get it to load I get these errors, no matter how simple the JSON file is.

The worst part is that I've got this to work in another script but for some reason, it refuses to work *here*. I've gone through the old one trying to figure out what I'm missing but I can't find it.

So instead of trying to just read a simple JSON file I'll give you the full thing I need to do and hopefully someone can help me out in here.

Code:

```
public List<string> PostalCodes = new List<string>();

public Client()
{
    try
    {
        string postals = LoadResourceFile(GetCurrentResourceName(), "new-postals.json");
        Debug.WriteLine(postals); // Outputs properly, actually can see the stuff

        dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(postals); //Newtonsoft.Json
        Debug.WriteLine(array[0]); // Not working at all.
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"^3[DEBUG] ^0Error info: {e.Message.ToString()}\r\n\r\n");
        throw;
    }
}
```

JSON File:

```json
[
    {
        "x":2325.4345703125,
        "y":5147.21484375,
        "code":"2000"
    },
    {
        "x":2151.2138671875,
        "y":5166.0888671875,
        "code":"2001"
    },
    // And so on.
]
```

If you wonder what `LoadResourceFile` it's loading and reading the file for me in one line of code.

**Edit:**

First, let me start by apologizing. As I'm still new to this I didn't include the whole error message as the rest that was given to me didn't look like it was useful.

```
[DEBUG] ^0Error info: The type initializer for 'Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultSerializationBinder' threw an exception.
MainThrd/ Failed to instantiate instance of script Client: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultSerializationBinder' threw an exception. ---> System.MethodAccessException: Error verifying Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultSerializationBinder:.ctor (): Method System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder:.ctor () is not accessible at 0x0001
MainThrd/   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultSerializationBinder..cctor () [0x00000] in <836484b0267d488c8d30f28b57efebd9>:0 
MainThrd/    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
MainThrd/   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Create () [0x00000] in <836484b0267d488c8d30f28b57efebd9>:0 
MainThrd/   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Create (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x00000] in <836484b0267d488c8d30f28b57efebd9>:0 
MainThrd/   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.CreateDefault () [0x00011] in <836484b0267d488c8d30f28b57efebd9>:0 
MainThrd/   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.CreateDefault (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x00000] in <836484b0267d488c8d30f28b57efebd9>:0 
MainThrd/   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x0000b] in <836484b0267d488c8d30f28b57efebd9>:0 
MainThrd/   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x00000] in <836484b0267d488c8d30f28b57efebd9>:0 
MainThrd/   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value) [0x00000] in <836484b0267d488c8d30f28b57efebd9>:0 
MainThrd/   at Client..ctor () [0x00071] in <7b9b05cb23034b40bf8a5d2ade61e392>:0 
MainThrd/   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
MainThrd/   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in <74fbbe963b7e417b8d715b858c5c584f>:0 
MainThrd/    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
MainThrd/   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00014] in <74fbbe963b7e417b8d715b858c5c584f>:0 
MainThrd/   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (System.Boolean nonPublic) [0x000a8] in <74fbbe963b7e417b8d715b858c5c584f>:0 
MainThrd/   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x00009] in <74fbbe963b7e417b8d715b858c5c584f>:0 
MainThrd/   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x00027] in <74fbbe963b7e417b8d715b858c5c584f>:0 
MainThrd/   at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Boolean nonPublic) [0x00020] in <74fbbe963b7e417b8d715b858c5c584f>:0 
MainThrd/   at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <74fbbe963b7e417b8d715b858c5c584f>:0 
MainThrd/   at CitizenFX.Core.InternalManager.CreateAssemblyInternal (System.String assemblyFile, System.Byte[] assemblyData, System.Byte[] symbolData) [0x000b1] in C:\gl\builds\edf06b9b\0\cfx\fivem\code\client\clrcore\InternalManager.cs:134
```

I did, however, get it to work with the answer below and changing the project reference. I did try the code first but it didn't resolve anything, I read a bit more about the problem and I decided to change the project reference after and just gave it a test run. It works perfectly now. Thank you all so much for all the help. Greatly appreciated!

Project Reference (CSPROJ)

```
// FROM
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>

// TO
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.0" ExcludeAssets="Compile" GeneratePathProperty="true" />
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.1\lib\portable-net40+sl5+win8+wp8+wpa81\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: I think you only posted _half_ the error message?

Comment: You might try cleaning and rebuilding.  See: [Loading dll that contains Newtonsoft assembly with reflection error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58904011/3744182).

Comment: What does array look like when you debug it?  Does it have anything in it?

Comment: We need some more info here: what error message are you getting, where is it throwing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to C#!

My first suggestion would be to avoid `dynamic` unless you have a good use case for it. In this scenario, I'd create a class to match your data

```cs
public class Data
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

Then use the generic version of `DeserializeObject` to type your deserialization, such as

```cs
var array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Data>>(postals);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped out a bunch. I still had the error code but I got it working. Seems like the reference generated with Visual Studio wasn't working.